# I left a bottle of water in the fridge for the past three months. I took it out today. There was a block of ice in it. How?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

How is this even possible?

I know my fridge is not freezing items. The bottle was sitting at the back and I totally forgot about it. I went to empty it and heard a clank and noticed there was ice in it. How does this make any sense? I don't think that the fridge is disproportionately cooling some regions to below zero. And if so, why would the bottle have a mix of that block of ice and water in it then?

Comment: Obviously, *it is* cooling some areas more than others. Look fro an air vent from the freezer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about fridges not chemistry ;)

Comment: See answer below. Looks like it IS chemistry-based. :)

Comment: About fridges? How do you ask a chemistry question that involves empirical results? Won't it involve something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The piping for refrigerant circulation is in the fridge walls, so obviously it's colder near the back as there is no heat from the front door reaching that area and heat exchange with compressor/coolant circuit is at maximum.

As for the partially frozen water, this happens to mineral water and water containing any salts in general. As water freezes out, the salinity increases, resulting in [freezing point depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression) for remaining solution. These processes are the basis for [fractional freezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_freezing).